# Passing down cumulative value in recursive cursor in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql

I have a tree structure as below.

[Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hXAb.png)

The requirement is to accumulate the Leadtimes of each parent and pass to child.

I currently have below query;

```
SELECT LEVEL AS struct_level
   ,t.part_no AS parent_part
   ,t.component_part AS comp_part_no
   ,NVL(t.lead_time ,0) AS comp_part_lead_time
   ,NVL(t.lead_time ,0) + NVL(PRIOR t.lead_time ,0) AS cumul_lead_time
FROM   ifsapp.prod_structure_cfv t
START  WITH (t.part_no) IN 'PART A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR (t.component_part) = (t.part_no)
ORDER  SIBLINGS BY t.component_part;
```

This will give me a data set like below.
[my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mdap.png)

But the issue is, the lead time should be calculated from the whole branch. I.e. the correct data set should be,
[correct data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySHO2.png)

As per my understanding, I can only refer PRIOR record values and/or master record (PART A) data via ROOT.

Is there a way to accomplish this please? Maybe using a recursive function?

I tried to reuse the recursive function mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201082/plsql-looping-through-hierarchy), but couldn't get desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (part_no, component_part, lead_time, cumul_lead_time) AS (
  SELECT part_no,
         component_part,
         COALESCE(lead_time, 0),
         COALESCE(lead_time, 0)
  FROM   ifsapp.prod_structure_cfv
  WHERE  part_no = 'PART A'
UNION ALL
  SELECT p.part_no,
         p.component_part,
         COALESCE(p.lead_time, 0),
         r.cumul_lead_time + COALESCE(p.lead_time, 0)
  FROM   rsqfc r
         INNER JOIN ifsapp.prod_structure_cfv p
         ON (r.component_part = p.part_no)
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY component_part SET order_rn
SELECT part_no,
       component_part,
       lead_time,
       cumul_lead_time
FROM   rsqfc;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prod_structure_cfv (part_no, component_part, lead_time) AS
SELECT 'PART A', 'PART B', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART A', 'PART C', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART B', 'PART D', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART B', 'PART E', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART B', 'PART F', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART C', 'PART G', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART C', 'PART H', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART D', 'PART P', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART D', 'PART Q', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART E', NULL,     2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART F', 'PART R', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART G', 'PART X', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART G', 'PART Y', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART H', NULL,     2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART P', NULL,     2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART Q', NULL,     1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART R', 'PART S', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART S', NULL,     3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART X', NULL,     1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PART Y', NULL,     2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PART_NO | COMPONENT_PART | LEAD_TIME | CUMUL_LEAD_TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | PART A | PART B | 0 | 0 |
> | PART B | PART D | 1 | 1 |
> | PART D | PART P | 0 | 1 |
> | PART P | *null* | 2 | 3 |
> | PART D | PART Q | 0 | 1 |
> | PART Q | *null* | 1 | 2 |
> | PART B | PART E | 1 | 1 |
> | PART E | *null* | 2 | 3 |
> | PART B | PART F | 1 | 1 |
> | PART F | PART R | 1 | 2 |
> | PART R | PART S | 0 | 2 |
> | PART S | *null* | 3 | 5 |
> | PART A | PART C | 0 | 0 |
> | PART C | PART G | 0 | 0 |
> | PART G | PART X | 3 | 3 |
> | PART X | *null* | 1 | 4 |
> | PART G | PART Y | 3 | 3 |
> | PART Y | *null* | 2 | 5 |
> | PART C | PART H | 0 | 0 |
> | PART H | *null* | 2 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1e8ad8e9ed357cf5de5d10bdd3181f13)*